# Node / Express Post request using a function to send data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I am using a function that prevents the default submit of a form and want to use a second function that posts this so i can work / modify the data in the fist function before submitting.

the first function

```
const Test = document.querySelector('.test')
Test.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const username = CreateUser.querySelector('.username').value
  const password = CreateUser.querySelector('.password').value
  post('/about', { username, password })
})
```

i found the following the function that submits the Post request. It works fine when the destination is another function without leaving the actual page.

```
function post (path, data) {
  return window.fetch(path, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
}
```

I use the following routing in my index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const store = require('./store')
const app = express()
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

var path = require('path')

app.post('/createUser', (req, res) => {
  store
    .createUser({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password
    })
    .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
})

app.get('/about',(req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public', 'about.html'));
})

app.post('/about',(req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public', 'about.html'));
})



app.listen(7555, () => {
  console.log('Server running on http://localhost:7555')
})
```

When i make a post to `/createUser` i works fine and i can insert the data to a mysql table using a function.
I now want to make a post to `/about` using a function and eventually pass the data.
Why does it not work? I dont get any error.
The about.html, index.html and the js file with my functions are all in the public folder.
thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Your route for the post function

```
app.post('/about',(req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public', 'about.html'));
})
```

is just returning the `about.html` page from your `public` folder. So there wouldn't be an error, you should just be getting back that HTML after posting to that endpoint with how it is currently configured.

The problem is that you'll only be getting this back as the body of your `fetch()` request. If you're wanting to see the `about.html` page, you'll want to actually redirect to `http://localhost:7555/about.html`. If you want to see the result of your `fetch()` request, you should be able to see the payload in the Networks tab of your DevTools (or your browser of choice's equivalent).

[image]

Comment: thanks for explaining it, could you please expand your answer to how i can get back the html of about.html, right now after submit it does nothing